# Select Subject CN from digital certificate using Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell

Looking to get a list of Personal digital certificates installed on a computer for the current user along with their "Issued To".  I am able to do most of it, except the (Issued To) which is also found in the details of the certificates under Subject(CN). This is my powershell command which returns a blank FriendlyName/IssuedTo:

```
Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Select FriendlyName, Issuer, NotAfter,NotBefore
```

Everything works just fine, but I need to get either the FriendlyName (Issued To) or Subject CN which is exactly the same. Thanks!

Comment: You could select SubjectName and parse out what's between `CN=` and the first `,`

Comment: Any ideas how to do that Dallas?

Comment: Follow [about_Calculated_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3) e.g. `@{Name='Issuer0'; Expression = {($_.Issuer.Split(','))[0]}}`

Comment: You could get your list of Subjectnames with something like this `$CNs = ( Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\CurrentUser\My ).Subjectname` and then to parse, something like this **foreach ($cn in $CNs){$cn.name.split(',')[0]}** would work if no commas are present in the CN, and that CN is listed first in all cases.   I am sure there is a much better way to do this, and there is probably a nice concise one liner somewhere to better get you what you are after in all cases, but that's how I would do it quickly.

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ I used your solution and split again to avoid "CN=" in front of the Issuer : `Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Select FriendlyName, @{Name='CNIssuer';Expression= {(($_.Issuer.Split(','))[0]).split('=')[1]}}, NotAfter,NotBefore`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below to get the result you're looking for. A few regex used for different situations because there are all kinds of certificates out there.

```
# Get all the certificates from the current user's personal store
[System.Object[]]$Certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My

# Create an empty array to store the output objects
[System.Object[]]$Output = @()

# Loop through each certificate and extract the relevant properties
foreach ($Cert in $Certs) {   

    # Takes care of certificate subjects that include comma in their CN
    # Determine if the subject contains a comma
    if ($Cert.Subject -match 'CN=(?<RegexTest>.*?),.*') {
        # If the CN value contains double quotes, use split to get the value between the quotes
        if ($matches['RegexTest'] -like '*"*') {
            $SubjectCN = ($Element.Certificate.Subject -split 'CN="(.+?)"')[1]
        }
        # Otherwise, use the named group RegexTest to get the CN value
        else {
            $SubjectCN = $matches['RegexTest']
        }
    }
    # If the subject does not contain a comma, use a lookbehind to get the CN value
    elseif ($Cert.Subject -match '(?<=CN=).*') {
        $SubjectCN = $matches[0]
    }

    # Create a custom object with the certificate thumbprint, subject, friendly name and subject CN
    $Output += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Thumbprint   = [System.String]$Cert.Thumbprint
        Subject      = [System.String]$Cert.Subject
        FriendlyName = [System.String]$Cert.FriendlyName
        SubjectCN    = [System.String]$SubjectCN
    }
}

# Display the output array
[System.String[]]$Output.SubjectCN
```